# How are Taylor and Maclaurin series applied in this situation?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I am a high school student that’s having a hard time figuring out what to carry out in his report. As we know that Newton’s law of cooling shows an exponential curve in other words. This question might be stupid, I haven’t started studying both series but I am really interested on carrying out something new.  Would it be possible to use both or any series into my analysis of Newton’s curve of cooling? If not in your opinion what can I include in the analysis of the curve (even most basic would be fine).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maclaurin series is a special case of Taylor, i.e. $x_0=0$.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to find a power series expansion for the exponential curve in Newton's law of cooling, which is of the form
$$ae^{bt}$$
where $a$ and $b$ are constants.

The Taylor series expansion for a function $f(x)$ at the point $a$ is
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}}(x-a)^{n}$$
where $f^{(n)}(a)$ denotes the $n$th derivative of $f$ evaluated at the point $a$.

The Maclaurin series expansion of $f$ is just the Taylor series of $f$ where $a=0$

Let's try to apply it to our function
$$f(t)=ae^{bt}$$
We first try to find some derivatives of $f$ in some point $a$.
let's choose for example $a=0$ (The Maclaurin series expansion).
$$f^{(1)}(t)=ab\cdot e^{bt} \Rightarrow f^{(1)}(0)=ab\cdot e^{b\cdot0}=ab$$
$$f^{(2)}(t)=ab^2\cdot e^{bt} \Rightarrow f^{(2)}(0)=ab^2\cdot e^{b\cdot 0}=ab^2$$
$$f^{(3)}(t)=ab^3\cdot e^{bt} \Rightarrow f^{(3)}(0)=ab^3\cdot e^{b\cdot 0}=ab^3$$

Do you see the pattern?
In general, we can obtain that
$$f^{(n)}(0)=a\cdot b^n$$

Now we ready to put everything together!
As I mentioned before, the Tayler series of $f$ at point $0$ (Maclaurin series) is
$$f(t)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}}t^n=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {a\cdot b^n}{n!}}t^n=a\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {b^n}{n!}}t^n$$

And we obtain that the Maclaurin series of $f$ is
$$f(t)=a\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {b^n}{n!}}t^n=a(1+bt+\frac{b^2}{2}t^2+\frac{b^3}{3!}t^3+\frac{b^4}{4!}t^4...)$$

I don't know how this can help you understand Newton's law of cooling physically
But I hope it helped. (This is my first time writing an answer so please have mercy on me in the comment section).

Comment: Looks good thanks a lot for your answer. Do you know how it is used or is it useful for the exponential curve in newton’s law of cooling?(what is the main point of doing these series in newton’s law of cooling?)

Comment: I don't know how this can help you. because Newton's law of cooling already provide you with an exact solution so you don't need to use those series for approximation. However I am not a physicist, and there might be a reason of doing such things. Anyway, if you do want to use those series, this is how they apply in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Newton law of cooling write
$$T(t)=T_{\text{env}}+(T_0-T_{\text{env}})\,e^{-\frac t \tau}$$ Since the time constant $\tau$ is positive, you can write
$$e^{-\frac t \tau}=\sum_{n=0}^p \frac{(-1)^n }{n!}\left(\frac{t}{\tau }\right)^n$$

Now, the question is too know how many terms you need to add for a given accuracy. Since this is an alternating series you want to know $p$ such that
$$\frac{1 }{(p+1)!}\left(\frac{t}{\tau }\right)^{p+1} \leq \epsilon$$ that is to say
$$(p+1)! \geq \frac 1  \epsilon \left(\frac{t}{\tau }\right)^{p+1}$$ and there are formulae to *approximate* very accurately $p$ (if you are concerned by this point, let me know and I shall elaborate).

If you use few terms, it could be better to use for approximation the so called Padé approximants which are sytematically much better than Taylor series. For example, around $x=0$,
$$e^{-x} \sim \frac {2-x}{2+x}$$
$$e^{-x} \sim \frac {12-6x+x^2}{12+6x+x^2}$$
are respectively $O(x^3)$ and $O(x^5)$.